# How do native speakers understand "make an acquaintance"?

Tags: meaning

Can you explain what it means?

Comment: It would be an extremely unusual thing to say (it's common enough to *make a friend*, but not an *acquaintance*). The normal idiomatic usage is *to make **someone's** acquaintance* (become acquainted with ***that particular** "someone"*). But it's a somewhat dated/formal usage, probably most often occuring in the formulaic *[I'm] pleased to have made your acquaintance*, which really just means *It was a pleasure to meet you*.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with a stranger, Mr. X. If you go up to him and engage in conversational interaction, or he approaches you, and the interaction is sufficiently satisfying for you to exchange names (and if Japanese, *meishi*), then you have made an acquaintance. Your acquaintances are those to whom you can put a name or about whom you can state something, even if only in the form "Thingy from Solihull who sells billiard tables". Friendship is not required, though many people do indeed confuse the two, not least on Facebook (there should be a button for "(un)acquaintancing".

Answer (score 0):

To make someone's acquaintance is to meet them where you each introduce yourself. Someone is your acquaintance when you know each other by name (not just you know them), will recognise each other and say hello when you meet, but you are not close enough to call your relationship a friendship.